# Second Unit Test Not Running

Tags: c#, unit-testing

I am having trouble getting my Method B test to run. The logic is fine, but when the unit tests are run, only Method A will run. If Method A and B are switched in terms of spots, only Method B will run. So clearly the code is wrong at some point. Do I need to call method B's test from inside method A in order to get both unit tests to run?

I'm pretty new to C#, so forgive my basic question.

```
using redacted;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;
using System;

namespace UnitTests
{
    [TestClass()]
    public class ClassTest
    {
        public TestContext TestContext{get;set;}

        [TestMethod()]
        public void MethodATest()
        {
            the unit test
        }

        [TestMethod()]
        public void MethodBTest()
        {
            the unit test
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This looks fine to me.  Are you sure there isn't some relevant code missing here?

Comment: How are you executing the tests?

Comment: Have you enabled exceptions? Perhaps sme CLR exception was thrown

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks fine.

Make sure you are running all test (Test->Run->All tests), not something like test in context (Ctrl+R, T) or have some sort of list of tests to run.

Comment: This worked. I'm not sure what happened, I kept hitting Run All Tests in Solution (Ctrl+R) and it would only run Method A Test. I closed everything down, and it still didn't work. So I went to lunch and when I came back I launched everything again and it worked. The only difference between to the two is I unchecked "Deploy the latest version of .NET CF" in the project properties. So I'm not sure if it was a cache problem or if that actually matters.